# How to use for range loop for 20 time for one samples of DataFrame

Tags: python

I need to get 20 Samples of DataFrame
Here is my code to get 1 sample of 10 rows

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df1 = df.iloc[:, -8:]
sample1 = df1.sample(10,replace=True,random_state=0) # this is for 1 sample of 10 rows
```

i need to use for range loop for 20 times and then return the mean of each column

Comment: Can you share how your data looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why you'd want to do that, but here is a way:

```py
pd.concat([
    df1.sample(10, replace=True).mean()
    for _ in range(20)
], axis=1).mean(axis=1)
```

Note: with `random_state=0`, you force all draws to be the same, and the mean is the same as that of a single draw.

Example after synthetic setup:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df1 = df.iloc[:, -8:]  # no-op in this case, since fewer than 8 columns
```

Example result of the code above:

```
A    54.476303
B    41.859940
C    50.512408
D    45.886166
dtype: float64
```

If instead you want to see the mean of each column for each draw:

```py
out = pd.concat([
    df1.sample(10, replace=True).mean()
    for _ in range(20)
], axis=1).T

>>> out
            A          B          C          D
0   47.465985  50.129386  58.124864  56.518534
1   58.923649  48.446715  46.776693  53.650037
2   60.992973  56.601188  48.049008  44.983743
3   61.546340  45.256996  50.442885  55.271372
4   46.988532  37.723527  64.090468  49.795228
5   55.474868  40.939143  48.870670  61.436648
6   51.768746  43.840800  43.764986  48.645581
7   40.390841  59.571081  51.644671  47.765832
8   48.935542  48.042567  38.030456  47.531566
9   65.405356  56.511895  51.500633  54.639754
10  55.374030  57.356247  47.312623  48.489651
11  51.058319  60.779529  40.204563  66.387166
12  54.733305  60.229638  70.569112  51.509640
13  66.992088  64.504027  42.853642  46.030091
14  50.050447  60.265275  44.487474  44.355356
15  68.018903  70.280004  35.764564  51.583207
16  41.462822  50.420280  32.341020  62.575607
17  38.148091  54.204553  40.006434  52.940808
18  58.230119  54.001817  59.826057  37.026755
19  67.777483  51.038580  39.947926  40.842169
```